# NInject chained conditional dependency

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, conditional-statements

I'm relatively new to Ninject, and I'm trying to figure out a relatively complex set of dependencies.

Basically what I've got is the following dependency chain:

```cs
class A {
    public A(IB b, IC c) { }
}

class B : IB {
    public B(IC c) { }
}

class C : IC { }

class SimulatedC : IC { }

class SimulatedA : A {
    public SimulatedA(IB b, IC c) : base(b, c) { }
}
```

the module initializes the binding as follows:

- Bind IC to C when injected into A
- Bind IC to SimulatedC when injected into SimulatedA

Now, here's the issue. Because both `A` and `SimulatedA`both inject `B`, and because `B` injects `IC`, I can't figure out how to set up the dependency chain to get the correct `IC` implementation injected into `B`.

Here's what I've tried:

```cs
this.Bind<IC>().To<C>().WhenInjectedInto<A>();
this.Bind<IC>().To<SimulatedC>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<SimulatedA>();
```

the result though is that the binding to `B` isn't described here, and `B` instantiated from `SimulatedA` gets injected `C` instead of `SimulatedC`.

I tried doing this:

```cs
this.Bind<IC>().To<C>().InCallScope();
this.Bind<IC>().To<SimulatedC>().InCallScope();
```

But NInject just laughed at me. (Multiple bindings exception.)

Any help?

Thanks!

Update: I figured out one way to do this:

```cs
this.Bind<IC>().To<C>().WhenNoAncestorMatches(ShouldBeSimulated);
this.Bind<IC>().To<SimulatedC>()
     .WhenAnyAncestorMatches(ShouldBeSimulated);


private static bool ShouldBeSimulated(IContext context)
{
    var request = context.Request.ParentRequest;
    while (request != null)
    {
        if (request.Service == typeof (SimulatedA))
        {
              return true;
        }
        request = request.ParentRequest;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Is this the best way to do it though?

Comment: What is your actual use case? What is this `SimulatedA` for a type. Is this a class you use for unit testing?

Comment: Not exactly. Basically think of it as a Proxy pattern -- A is, let's say Database, and SimulatedA is, let's say, file system. (to be exact, A is the phone's GPS sensor, and SimulatedA is pre-recorded location data.) C is Environment.TickCount, and SimulatedC is time offset associated with the pre-recorded coordinate.

Comment: I think you don't need the `while` loop when you're using `WhenAnyAncestorMatches`, because the check will be executed for every ancestor, anyway.